# c++ Reading in integers from a .txt file to a stack

Tags: c++, ifstream

This is so stupid. I've been stuck literally for an hour trying to read in a .txt file of numbers that are separated by a single whitespace. The while loops only gets executed once for some reason!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string line;
    string str(argv[1]);
    ifstream myfile((str).c_str());
    int num;
    stack<int> x;

    while (myfile >> num);
    {
        x.push(num);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, look at this line more closely:

```
while (myfile >> num);
```

Eventually, you'll notice the semi-colon. The compiler thinks this means you want a loop that does nothing (the semi-colon here indicates a single, empty statement). So, the loop reads in all the numbers, but does nothing with them.

The next section is interpreted separately as a statement in its own scope (denoted by the braces), to be executed after the loop:

```
{
    x.push(num);
}
```

All that does is push the last number read onto the stack, leading you to think the loop only executes once.

Remove the `;` and you're OK! Once bitten by this, you'll never forget ;-)

On an unrelated note, it's a bit silly to take `argv[1]` (a C-style string), put it into a `string` object, then use `c_str()` to turn that back into a C-string for the ifstream constructor. Just use `argv[1]` directly, since you're not doing anything else with it. Also, it would be a good idea to check `argc` first and make sure that a filename was passed in. Finally, you should check that the file was successfully opened instead of assuming it -- at the very least make your assumption explicit with an `assert(myfile.is_open());`. Oh, and you don't use the `line` variable at all.

Comment: Maybe now you'll appreciate why people insist that you enable all compiler warnings, always...

Comment: @CyberShot: No problem ;-) I've added a paragraph to my answer nitpicking the rest of your code, just FYI.

Comment: @KerrekSB I used the -Wall flag and got no warnings.

Comment: @Cameron Under what circumstances would a file not open correctly? Random operating system error?

Comment: @CyberShot: Use more warnings: `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @CyberShot: Good question. There's always lots of error conditions, especially with IO. Perhaps the filename specified does not exist (because of a typo or the wrong working directory). Or the program doesn't have appropriate permissions to open the file. Or the file is on a SAN and the network failed at the wrong moment. Or the filesystem is (partially?) corrupted. Or the file was deleted between the time it was specified and the time you try to open it. And, as you say, there's always random OS errors :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks. "@"Cameron You sound like an expert in the field! Thanks

Comment: @CyberShot: No problem, but I'm by no means an expert. Error checking is just part of good programming practice (since errors are inevitable). Sometimes it's even a good idea to add ["sanity checks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_testing#Software_development) (see second-to-last paragraph) on stuff that should always be OK, just in case -- obviously, that level of error detection is less important in toy applications and more important in space shuttle software. Robustness (and readability, maintainability, etc.) is an important part of development and isn't always given enough attention